# How can I explicitly disable TLS when sending to one specific recipient?

Tags: smtp, email-server, sendmail, tls, starttls

I have a SendMail 8.14 server deployed in the middle of an SMTP workflow (Outbound mail looks like **Exchange -> SendMail -> Appliance -> Internet**)

I have TLS configured for the first three hosts.  This works fine for the most part but I need to temporarily disable TLS when sending to ONE specific recipient (appinbox@example.com) for troubleshooting purposes.

The issue is that I don't want to disable TLS for the 99.999% of traffic, nor do I want to disable it for messages going to joe@example.com.

Is there a way I can tell sendmail to selective NOT use opportunistic STARTTLS if (and only if) I'm sending to appinbox@example.com?

I know the `try_TLS` ruleset supports hosts, domain, and IPs, but does it support an *individual* email address?

Comment: Would blocking per outgoing host fix your problem?

Comment: Hmmm... I don't think so. I'm trying to verify if a bug exists with a product and in order to do that, I need to prove what the message body looked in in transit as it left Sendmail.  Hence why I'm trying to selectively turn off tls but just for this specific message.

Comment: Would forcing plain SMTP for deliveries to the recipient satisfy your requirement?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip yes but to be clear, I don't want to disable startls for other recipients (even though I'm smart hosting everything to the same downstream host).

Comment: There is F= flag to disable ESMTP in mailer definition.  You can select mailer per single recipient using LOCAL_RULE_0.  But I am under impression that you want something more foolproof and less improvised [e.g. connections caching/reuse could create problems]

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip That sounds like something that would work.  I'm confused on what you mean by "more foolproof and less improvised".  This is indeed a production system so if that change would be prone to instability issues, I'd shy away from it.